# Passing a parameter to ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf-2.2, payara

I have the following menu items in `index.xhtml`

```
<p:menuitem ajax="false" value="A" action="#{bean.start('A')}" />
<p:menuitem ajax="false" value="B" action="#{bean.start('B')}" />
```

The following code on my backing bean doesn't work when the bean is `ViewScoped` (I don't want to make it `SessionScoped`):

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

private LetterEnum letter;

public String findBSEmpty(String str) {
    if (saison.equals("A")) {
        this.letter = LetterEnum.A;
        return "a.xhtml";
    } else {
        this.letter = LetterEnum.B;
        return "b.xhtml";
    }
}

public void doSomthing(){
    //Method called from other a.xhtml and b.xhtml
    //Processing data depending on the value of "letter"
}
```

I know that view scoped beans are recycled after every view change and I have must start from `index.xhtml` and depending on the choice of the user, the application will display `a.xhtml` or `b.xhtml` to continue processing other data. 
Am I missing somthing?

What are the best practices about this kind of navigation?

BTW, I am using JSF 2.2 with Payara 4

Comment: There are multiple questions on stackoverflow about [passing parameters between pages (and their corresponding beans)](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+parameter+between+pages+jsf+site%3Astackoverflow.com). But there is also a ['viewaccessscoped' in DeltaSpike](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+parameter+between+pages+jsf+site%3Astackoverflow.com+"%40viewaccessscoped") which might help out as well.

Comment: I already saw those :(

Comment: why the 'said' face then? They **help** (and I would not mind if, like requested in [ask], you mention what you searched, keep track of important links, post them to and mention why the cannot be used or do not work)

Comment: What is not working properly? The question is a bit vague.